# Isomorphic Strings in Python

Tags: python, string, algorithm, time-complexity, isomorphism

Here's my code:

```
def isIso(x,y):
  if len(x) != len(y):
    return False
  for i in range(len(x)):
    count = 0
    if x.count(x[i]) != y.count(y[i]):
      return False
  return True
```

Why do all solutions for this question online involve mapping or dictionaries? I'm wondering why everyone seems to be overcomplicating the solution to this problem. Is it a time complexity thing? The time complexity of this is n which is not ideal - are people using maps/dictionaries because of a better time complexity?

Comment: Your code decides if x and y are anagrams, which are different from isomorphic strings. Usually "Isomorphic strings" refers to things like `ladder` and `bigger`, where the double-ds correspond to the double-gs, and you can get a consistent mapping `l to b, a to i, d to g, e to e, and r to r`.

Comment: @MitchelPaulin The OP has posted a solution that's not O(N). :)

Comment: @Dennis Are you sure of this - can you think of two words that would cause my code to fail? I tested ladder and bigger and and my code returns True. It returns true for "egg" and "add" - returns False for "foo" and "bar". All test cases I have tried have succeeded

Comment: @Dennis also the code is not checking for anagrams, else it would return False for ladder and bigger as well as egg and add

Comment: @SoftEngStudent Are the strings "aabb" and "abab" considered isomorphic?

Comment: @MarkDickinson Ah, I thought they were! My code as well as solution below will return that they are. However, I ran this on an online example and it said they were not. I know those two are anagrams but I considered them both to be isomorphic as well. I thought isomorphic meant checking if the letters in the strings occurred the same amount of times. So for example, my code would also return true for "aabb" and "xyxy".  I'm incorrect here aren't I? If so, thank you for proposing something that breaks my code!

Answer (score 2):

> The time complexity of this is n which is not ideal

No! Your time complexity is not on the order of n. It is on the order of n<sup>2</sup>.

`str.count` must loop through the entire string every time, n operations. And you call it n times. So the result is n*n = n<sup>2</sup> complexity, much much worse than if you store the counts in a dictionary and look them up.

The simplest implementation in Python that would be on the order of n time is:

```
from collections import Counter
def is_isomoprhic(x, y):
    xc, yc = Counter(x), Counter(y)
    return all(xc[a] == xc[b] for a, b in zip(x, y))
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but this is a solution for anagrams. What I am looking for is a solution for Isomorphic Strings. If you run my code, you can see it is solving for isomorphic strings.

Comment: But thank you for pointing out my mistake in calculating the time complexity!

Comment: @SoftEngStudent I misunderstood the purpose of your code. I updated the implementation to one for isomorphic strings.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution you will ever find --- Thank you!!!

```
len(set(zip(list(s), list(s1)))) == len(set(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and [translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).

```
def is_isometric(x: str, y: str) -> bool:
    trans = str.maketrans(x, y)
    return x.translate(trans) == y
```